# Show the user who was banned discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this code to ban spammers:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    counter = 0
    with open("spam_detect.txt", "r+") as file:
        for lines in file:
            if lines.strip("\n") == str(message.author.id):
                counter += 1

        file.writelines(f"{str(message.author.id)}\n")
        if counter > 5:
            await message.guild.ban(message.author, reason="Spammer")
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            await message.guild.unban(message.author)
            await message.channel.send("Banned for spam")
            print("banned")
```

The user gets softbanned, the messages get deleted, but i can only get it to say `Banned for spam`..and with the bot wiping everything that user did i cannot know who was banned and when. How can i get it to say `<USER> was banned for spam` ?

Comment: Use f-strings like this: `f"{message.author} was banned for spam."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally don't recommend doing heavy stuff like this in an `on_message` event.
I recommend using a cache, and add the user as usual.

But to answer your question:

```
if counter > 5:
    await message.guild.ban(message.author, reason="Spammer")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await message.guild.unban(message.author)
    await message.channel.send(f"Banned {message.author.name} for spam")
    print("banned")
```

I added `f"Banned {message.author.name} for spam"`. This shows the name from the user that was banned. If you want to get the whole name with discriminator, do `message.author` instead.